# How can make the three-panel content of HomepageFeatures.js clickable?

Tags: docusaurus

[three panels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyyUQ.png)
In Docusaurus V2 I am editing HomepageFeatures.js for the three panels. What I would like to do is make them clickable so that they link to the relevant sections.

In the image here this would mean the first picture, or title (Tutorials), or even the text paragraph, would link through to the Tutorials page.

Any ideas how to do that?

The code section is:

```json
`const FeatureList = [
  {
    title: "Tutorials",
    Svg: require("../../static/img/Pyetrosyan_awesome.svg").default,
    description: (
      <>
        In these tutorials, you will find detailed instructions on how to install and set up 
        the software, as well as information on its various features and functions. We have 
        also included troubleshooting tips and best practices to help you get the greatest value 
        from the software.
      </>
    ),
  },`
```